# How to properly close a JFrame when logging off and connecting back to log off frame?

Tags: java, swing

I need help on figuring out how to do a proper Project about a Movie database, and I was in charge of more or less working with the NetBeans IDE, which I had never tried before, even tho is like a visual studios with Java.

The problem I had been facing is that I want to properly replace  this.

```
private void btnLogoffActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    
{                                          
    setVisible(false);
    LoginMovie l = new LoginMovie();
    l.setVisible(true);
}
```

to have the `JFrame` properly close  so I can have the user or admin return to the Log in `JFrame`, which is also comprised of this.

```
/*
 * aTo change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package luisdiazcomp4430;

/**
 *
 * @author game6
 */
public class LoginMovie extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form LoginMovie
     */
    public LoginMovie() {
        initComponents();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        lblUser = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblPass = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtUser = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnCancel = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnRegister = new javax.swing.JButton();
        txtPass = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        lbLogo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btnLogin = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jPasswordField1.setText("jPasswordField1");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Welcome, Poke movie Rents");

        lblUser.setText("UserName");

        lblPass.setText("Password");

        btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnCancelActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnRegister.setText("Register");
        btnRegister.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnRegisterActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lbLogo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/luisdiazcomp4430/PokeMovieRentsLogo.png"))); // NOI18N

        btnLogin.setText("Log in");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnLoginActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(lbLogo)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(4, 4, 4)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(lblPass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(128, 128, 128))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(btnLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 105, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(btnCancel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnRegister, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 98, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lblUser, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(txtPass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 124, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(txtUser, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 124, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(lbLogo)
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lblUser)
                    .addComponent(txtUser, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lblPass)
                    .addComponent(txtPass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 49, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(btnCancel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(btnRegister, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(btnLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        lblUser.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("lblUsername");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnRegisterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // code to hide login and open Register

        setVisible(false);
        RegisterJframe register ;
        register = new RegisterJframe();
        register.setVisible(true);


    }                                           

    private void btnCancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
     System.exit(0);        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                         

    private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        // TODO add your handling code
        String username = txtUser.getText();

        if ( username.contains("u") ) 
        {
        setVisible(false);
        userMainframe juser = new userMainframe();
        juser.setVisible(true);

        } 
        else if (username.contains("a") )
        {
        setVisible(false);
        adminMainframe jAdmin = new adminMainframe();
        jAdmin.setVisible(true);

        }
        else
        {


        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginMovie.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LoginMovie().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnCancel;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnLogin;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnRegister;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbLogo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblPass;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblUser;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField txtPass;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtUser;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Any idea what I should edit or change to make it work? And also this is not the finish log in code, since I was told by my peers that I  "pull the Data from the SQL database"

Comment: It sounds more like you need some kind of controller that can monitor the windows and make decisions about the navigation based on the current state of the app

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)